# How can I use {$login_form} a variable in header.tpl, whatever the page?

Tags: php, smarty, prestashop-1.7

I'd like to set a login form in a popin include in the header.tpl file.

When I'm on the authentication page, it works fine. But anywhere else, $login_form is undefined.

I use:
`{render file='customer/_partials/login-form.tpl' ui=$login_form}`

Controller:

```
$this->context->smarty->assign([
    'login_form' => $login_form->getProxy(),
]);

$this->setTemplate('customer/authentication');
```

I tried

```
$this->setTemplate('_partials/header');
```

but I still have symfony error.

Comment: Just curious -  I'm surprised you are using Smarty in preference to Twig

Comment: Not a choice, it's on prestashop ;)

Comment: According to the prestashop-1.7 tag above both twig and smarty are available.

Comment: Good to know, thanks!